# CopyWebpack : Error while trying to copy files from node_modules to my public

Tags: webpack, font-awesome, copy-webpack-plugin

## Context

First I did a lot of research, but I did not succeed.

I am using django as backend, and to manage my frontend dependencies I am using [webpack (starter)](https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter) which I modified to fit my needs.

Here is a part of my structure for the npm / webpack management :

- frontend

  - src
  - public
  - build

    - public

I am using CopyWebpackPlugin to manage my assets, like images and fonts. All assets placed in the `public` folder are correctly copied to the `build/public`.
However, I tried to add a new pattern entry to get fonts from fontawesome located in node_modules and copy it to the `build/public` folder, but I get errors whatever I am trying. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

## Pattern entries

```
output: {
    path: Path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
    filename: 'js/[name].js',
},
...
new CopyWebpackPlugin(
{
        patterns: [
            {from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'), to: 'public'},
            {
                from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts'),
                to: 'public/fonts'
            },
        ]
    }
),
```

## Error

> ERROR in Plugin name should be specified

So I tried to get only one file, by naming explicitly via `to`, and it is **working**.

```
{
    from: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot'),
    to: 'public/fonts/fa-brands-400.eot'
},
```

But I would like to get it working through the entire folder.
Then I wonder that the problem was caused by the module rules :

```
{
    test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
    },
},
```

I tried some modifications, but I didn't came to any solution.

## Edit

I also tried this @Andrey : isolate the process for fonts and images in their own `test`. Well nothing changes :/

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
    /* Exclude images while working with fonts, e.g. .svg can be both image or font. */
    exclude: Path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/images'),
    use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: 'fonts/'
        },
    },
},
```

Even removing these test led me to the same error. So I guess it is from my patterns definition.

I saw that there was 3 errors on `name`, so I have removed the three `.svg` files from the webfonts node_modules. And it has built successfully. So I am still stuck because I don't know how is it possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth to try to remove [path] from loader settings. Not sure how webpack is expected to treat loaded files which contain full path in their name when you ask CopyPlugin to copy them.

Comment: I thought too, but it did not resolve my issue. But of course, I will keep it without `[path]` you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a dumb...

I figure out that it was my `image-minimizer-webpack-plugin` attempting to apply optimizations on the 3 `.svg` webfonts.

```
new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
    minimizerOptions: {
        // Lossless optimization with custom option
        plugins: [
            ['gifsicle', {interlaced: true}],
            ['jpegtran', {progressive: true}],
            ['optipng', {optimizationLevel: 5}],
            [
                'svgo',
                {
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            removeViewBox: false,
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        ],
    },
}),
```

At the moment, I have deactivated the `svgo` part, and it is working well. Eventually I would try to exclude the optimization when the svg come from the node_modules